# Modified the text in excel cell?

Tags: excel

Let say the text in excel column is in this way

```
column A
12-98764G1
13-5746FR2
14-123H1
```

I would like to change it into two column, such as

```
column B           column C
KK-12-98764        G1
KK-13-05746        FR2
KK-14-00123        H1
```

Any ideas please?

Thanks

Comment: When you say cell do you mean column? Showing the results you expect without the logic behind it is not very helpful, can update your question and explain what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. Yes it is column not cell. I will modified it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cell `B1` enter the following array formula and confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
="KK-"&LEFT(A1,3)&TEXT(MID(A1,4,MATCH(1,ISERROR(VALUE(MID(MID(A1,4,99),ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(MID(A1,4,99)))),1)))*1,)-1),"00000")
```

In cell `C1` enter the following array formula and confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=MID(A1,MATCH(1,ISERROR(VALUE(MID(MID(A1,4,99),ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(MID(A1,4,99)))),1)))*1,)+3,99)
```

After entering these formulas, copy down as far as you need. To do that you need to select the 2nd row and down before pasting.

**EDIT**

To confirm array formulas on Excel for Mac, I believe the keyboard sequence is:

> <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and then press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>RETURN</kbd>.

.

**HERE IS HOW THE FORMULAS WORK**

At the heart of the formulas for both columns is a sub-formula that reports the position of the first non-numeric character in A1:

```
MATCH(1,ISERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(A1))),1)))*1,)
```

The problem with that is that it would always find the 'dash' character in position three. So we modify this sub-formula to begin the search after the 'dash' character:

```
MATCH(1,ISERROR(VALUE(MID(MID(A1,4,99),ROW(OFFSET($A$1,,,LEN(MID(A1,4,99)))),1)))*1,)
```

Once we have this position it is just a matter of pre-pending the "KK-" and moving bits around to match your patterns. That's easy. The challenging part is finding the first non-numeric character.

The only other wrinkle is formatting the number portion after the dash character so that it always includes five digits. That's done by supplying the TEXT() function with the "00000" format string.

Comment: Sorry, I have slightly modified my question by changing cell into column so that others will understand but I think the meaning is still the same. Thank you for replying.

Comment: I paste the array formula into cell B1 and cell C1, both results turn out to be #N/A. I am using Excel for mac 2011. By the way, for the array formula in cell B1, is it A1 or A2 (the original input text is in A1)?  Because it is different from the array formula of C1, since it is A1 not A2.

Comment: You need to confirm the formula entries differently on a Mac. I believe this is how:  CONTROL+U and then press ⌘+RETURN

Comment: Don't paste the formulas in the cells. Instead select a cell, then click in the formula bar at the top. Then confirm with the keyboard combination of: CONTROL+U and the press ⌘+RETURN.  You do this for B1 and then again for C1.

Comment: Oh... I see what you mean about A2. Yes it is A1. Type. I fixed the answer.

Comment: Nice!!! It works. If possible, could you briefly explain how you came out with this formula?

Comment: @pill45 I have update the answer with a short explanation of how the formulas work.